# How can I use Pandas to replace certain values in Excel data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a short Python script that uses `pandas` to read an Excel file and then create a `SQL INSERT` command.

Inside the script, I need to replace certain character strings.

However, when I do, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Here is my script:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('JulyData.xlsx')

# print(df)

# print(df.iloc[0, 0])

print('INSERT INTO project(name, object, amount, value)')
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    rowString = row
    rowString = rowString.replace(' " ', " ")
    rowString = rowString.replace(' â€“ ', " ")
    rowString = rowString.replace(' / ', " & ")
    rowString = rowString.replace(' â€™ ', " ")
    print(f'VALUES {tuple(rowString)}')
    print(f'WAITFOR DELAY \'00:00:02\'')
    print('\n')
```

Is there a way to do this in `pandas`?

Thanks!

sample output:

```
{'name': ['Xuâ€“, Yi', 'Gare, /Mark'], 'object': ['xuy@anesâ€™.mty.edu', '"gareg@msu.edu'], 'amount': ['100', '200'], 'value': ['"abc"', 'def']}
```

Comment: `Pandas` is the name of the namedtuple `row`, is has no method replace. You should use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: @Stef but I am using `replace`? Or am I not using it correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the `replace` method of pandas, not a non-existing `replace` method of a nametuple. If you can share a short example (output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`) I can post an answer.

Comment: @Stef ok thanks!  I edited my question and included short sample at the end.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pandas` is the name of the namedtuple `row` returned by `interrows`, and a namedtuple of course has no method `replace`. What you need is the pandas method [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) (for the whole data frame) or the string assessor's [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) (for individual columns).

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Xuâ€“, Yi', 'Gare, /Mark'], 'object': ['xuy@anesâ€™.mty.edu', '"gareg@msu.edu'], 'amount': ['100', '200'], 'value': ['"abc"', 'def']})
#          name               object amount  value
#0    Xuâ€“, Yi  xuy@anesâ€™.mty.edu    100  "abc"
#1  Gare, /Mark       "gareg@msu.edu    200    def

df.replace(['"',  'â€“', '/', 'â€™'],
           ['',  '', '&', '' ],
           regex=True)
```

Result:

```
          name            object amount value
0       Xu, Yi  xuy@anes.mty.edu    100   abc
1  Gare, &Mark     gareg@msu.edu    200   def
```

Comment: Thanks, what are all the `\1` and `\2` for? thanks again

Comment: These are placeholders for matched parts, you don't need them, sorry - my bad. I've updated the answer with your data.